# Printing Array Values on Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

How do you print all values in an array onto the modal dialog?
I have tried the code below but it only prints the last array value.

```
for (var count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(arr[count]);
  var arrayOutput = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Test');
}
```

Comment: What is in the `arr` array ?

Comment: @rupam for example 10 elements in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`showModalDialog()` method does not suspend the server-side script while the dialog is open.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui?hl=en#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title)

The script should show all the elements one by one. But a newer dialog might close the older one. So, you probably only see the last one. If you want to show all the elements in one dialog, use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
  HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    JSON.stringify(arr,null,2)
  ), 'Test'
);
```

Or if you want to see them one by one, use `Utilities.sleep()`:

```
for (var count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(arr[count]);
  var arrayOutput = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Test');
  Utilities.sleep(15*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can just use join method

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(arr.join(","),"Test")
```

or

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(arr),"Test")
```